# Why are Corda contracts a separate module in the Kotlin CorDapp template?

Tags: kotlin, corda

In the Kotlin CorDapp [template](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin) the contracts (and states) are a separate module than workflows.

What is the reason for this separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons for this:

1. Each Corda transaction also includes the jar containing the contract definition as an attachment. This is done to ensure that the correct contract is available when a transaction is validated at a later point in time (Considering the contract may upgrade over time). Thus separating the contract and flows jar reduces the size of the contract jar being attached to the transaction and thus reduces the size of the transaction. See more here: https://docs.corda.net/writing-a-cordapp.html#modules
2. It helps in upgrades. Contracts have constraints and thus contract upgrades take a rather complex path. Also, we anticipate that the contacts are less prone to upgrades than the flows. Hence separating them in separate modules allows for easy upgrades when one just requires to upgrade the flows, which can be done just by replacing the old flow jar with the newer one. Learn more here: https://medium.com/corda/contract-upgrades-and-constraints-in-corda-425055a9a47f

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation Ashutosh!